# Status code 200, but getting storage error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, multer-s3

I am using dio for sending my request to database. I tried to uplaod an image along with the "purpose field and send to database using multipartfile as follows:

```
uploadImages(token, productimage, purpose) async {
try {  
  dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
  print("___________IN upload images__________________");
  String fileName = productimage.path.split('/').last;    
  FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
    "productImage": 
        await MultipartFile.fromFile(productimage.path, filename: fileName),
    "purpose": purpose,
  });
  var b = await dio.post(
      'api',
      data: formData);
  print(b.statusCode);
  print(b);
  print("___________IN upload images__________________");
  return b;
} on DioError catch (e) {
  print("Here I am in upload image error");
}
```

I have restricted the file quality to 50, size to 500,500 and picking image using image_picker. I do not know why I am getting storage error.
I am using nodejs in the backend.
I am getting {scaled_IMG_20210603_233006.jpg} in fileName, {/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.shop_app/files/Pictures/scaled_IMG_20210603_233006.jpg} in productImage.path and {"check"} in purpose.

Edited:
When I set content type

```
dio.options.headers['Content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
```

I get `I/flutter (32229): 200 I/flutter (32229): {"error":{}}`
When I remove content-type
I get `I/flutter (32229): 200 I/flutter (32229): {"error":{"storageErrors":[]}}`
And when I set content type

```
dio.options.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/octet-stream';
```

I get `I/flutter (32229): 200 I/flutter (32229): Error: No File Selected`

Answer (score 0):

All the storage permission in your android manifest file.

Comment: Would you like to elaborate a bit?

Comment: Always worth a quick google when you don't know something. 

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: @CaseyDaniel it's not helping, I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` but getting the same error.